# Unify data from various requests in Node.js

Tags: node.js

On my current project in node.js (where I'm a beginner), there is a source of data that can be queried (WEB API) but is restricted to a certain amount of entries from a given position. It is not possible to request the full record set (eg. 1000 entries) you only can select a maximum of 50 Entries from an offset.

The function to get the data is as follow:

```
let myResponseData = await client.getData({userId: myId, first: 50, after: cursor});
```

where `userId` is an authentication, `first` is the number of records I want to request (0-50), and `after` is the cursor

the response looks like this:

```
{
  "totalRecords": 1000,
  "page_info": {
    "has_next_page": true,
    "end_cursor": "this is some random string"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id:" 1,
      "name": "Name1"
    },
    {
      "id:" 2,
      "name": "Name2"
    }
  ]
}
```

My current progress in fetching all data is, that i've already constructed a function that reads all pages from the data source like this:

```
 let myResponseData = await client.getData({userId: myId});
 let hasNextPage = myResponseData.page_info.next_page;
 let cursor = myResponseData.page_info.cursor;
 
 while(hasNextPage){
  console.log('next...' + cursor);
  myResponseData= await client.getData({ userId: myId, first: 50, after: cursor});
  hasNextPage = myResponseData.page_info.next_page;
  cursor = myResponseData.page_info.cursor;
  myFunctionToJoinData(myResponseData); //Here i need help
}
```

This works so far since the console logs the next + random string.
My goal is to end up with a json data object like in the request, but having all the entries from all queries

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you want to join all request results on the one JSON object?

Comment: Yes, i want a JSON object that contains all fetches entries combined

Comment: You can create an array and every time you get the result, you can simply push them into the array.